# autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" and WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Tags: solr

I'm new to solr. My solr instance version is:

Solr Specification Version: 3.1.0
Solr Implementation Version: 3.1.0 1085815 - grantingersoll - 2011-03-26 18:00:07
Lucene Specification Version: 3.1.0
Lucene Implementation Version: 3.1.0 1085809 - 2011-03-26 18:06:58
Current Time: Tue Apr 26 08:01:09 CEST 2011
Server Start Time:Tue Apr 26 07:59:05 CEST 2011

I have following definition for textgen type:

```
<fieldType name="textgen" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false">
  <analyzer type="index">
 <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" preserveOriginal="1"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="15" side="front" preserveOriginal="1"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
 <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
 ignoreCase="true"
 words="stopwords.txt"
 enablePositionIncrements="true"/>
 <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" preserveOriginal="1"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I'm using this type for name field in my index. As you can see I'm using autoGeneratePhraseQueries="false" but for query sony vaio 4gb I'm getting following query in debug:

```
<lst name="debug"> 
  <str name="rawquerystring">sony vaio 4gb</str> 
  <str name="querystring">sony vaio 4gb</str> 
  <str name="parsedquery">+name:sony +name:vaio +MultiPhraseQuery(name:"(4gb 4) gb")</str> 
  <str name="parsedquery_toString">+name:sony +name:vaio +name:"(4gb 4) gb"</str>
```

Do you have any idea how can I avoid this MultiPhraseQuery?

Answer (score 0):

Robert Muir answered on solr user mailing list:

> What do you have in solrconfig.xml for
>   luceneMatchVersion?
>
> If you don't set this, then its going
>   to default to "Lucene 2.9" emulation
>   so that old solr 1.4 configs work the
>   same way. I tried your example and it
>   worked fine here, and I'm guessing
>   this is probably whats happening.
>
> the default in the
>   example/solrconfig.xml looks like
>   this:
>
> ```
> <!-- Controls what version of Lucene various components of Solr
>     adhere to.  Generally, you want to use the latest version to
>     get all bug fixes and improvements. It is highly recommended
>     that you fully re-index after changing this setting as it can
>     affect both how text is indexed and queried.
>  -->
> <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_31</luceneMatchVersion>
> ```

It worked for me.